# Particular solution of $t^2y''-2y=t^2$ using the method of variation of parameters

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Using the Anzats $y(t) = t^r$, we find $r(r-1)-2=0$ and thus the fundamental set of solutions $y_1(t)=t^2$ and $y_2(t)=t^{-1}$.

We have $W[y_1,y_2](t) = y_1(t)y'_2(t)-y_1'(t)y_2(t) = -t^2 t^{-2} - 2t t^{-1} = -3$.

The method of variation of parameters now gives a particular solution of the form $y_p(t) = u_1(t)y_1(t)+u_2(t)y_2(t)$ with $$u_1'(t) = -\frac{t^2 y_2(t)}{W[y_1,y_2](t)} = \frac{1}{3} t$$ and $$u_1'(t) = \frac{t^2 y_1(t)}{W[y_1,y_2](t)} = -\frac{1}{3}t^4.$$

Hence, we have $u_1(t) = \frac{1}{6}t^2$ and $u_2(t) = -\frac{1}{15}t^5$. This gives $$y_p=u_1(t)y_1(t)+u_2(t)y_2(t) = \bigg( \frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{15} \bigg)t^4  = \frac{1}{10}t^4\ .$$

Inserting this into the ODE $L[y] = t^2y''-2y$, results in $L[y_p]=t^4$, not $t^2$.

[Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=t%5E2+y%27%27-2y+%3D+t%5E2) gives the particular solution $y_p(t) = \frac{1}{3}t^2 \log (t)$

**Question:** why does my application of the method of variation of parameters give a wrong particular solution? Where have I made a mistake?

Context: this is problem 2.4.9 of Braun's Differential Equations and Their Applications.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze My application of the variation of parameters leads me to a wrong particular solution. I'm wondering where I've made a mistake.

Comment: Ok after your edit the question is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the differential equation in the classical form before to apply the method of variation of parameters:
$$y''+b(t)y'+c(t)y=f(t)$$
$$y''-\dfrac 2{t^2}y=\color{red}{1}$$

---

So now you have that:
$$u_1'(t) = -\frac{ y_2(t)}{W[y_1,y_2](t)} = \frac{1}{3t} $$
And
$$u_1'(t) = \frac{ y_1(t)}{W[y_1,y_2](t)} = -\frac{1}{3}t^2$$

Answer (score 1):

You have first to put the equation in the form
$$
y''+P(t)y'+Q(t)y=R(t)
$$